# share pyenv environent for any user using the project

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyenv

Pyenv generates env in user's home folder, which is a problem for sharing environment

1. I do not want to install NLP and ML packages for each user
2. I do not want to have more than single point of truth when running a project

I am familiar of separate `virtualenv` package (and that would be my last resort) but wondering if there is a well-known `pyenv` strategy on that?

Comment: you should be saving your dependencies in a requirement.txt file or an environment.yaml file (or Pipfile) or really any other lock file in version control.

Comment: Are you using `pyenv` for a specific reason, or did you just pick it as 'any' package environment manager. In that case, you're probably better off using `virtualenv`. And installing packages for all users system-wide is not a recommended practice and can cause all sorts of admin and development nightmares, are you sure this is what you absolutely need?

Comment: Thanks @asosnovsky we do that, but that doesn't help, I am talking about shared dev server where more than to people are working on the SAME folder (not just project), and we do not want constantly sync, we are even parallel-programming with skype at the same time, and the workflow where we have the same folder with the project but still separate environments is really meaningless

Comment: Hi @Grismar, I use pyenv for easy management of various python version. What I understand `pyenv` is using properly `virtualenv` as I run: `pyenv virtualenv 3.8.6 python3.8.6_env` but the problem is that it ends up in user space, and we need shared virtualenv folder that more co-devs can start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set PYENV_ROOT for each user:
`export PYENV_ROOT="/usr/bin/.pyenv"`
This will make pyenv store environments in `/usr/bin/.pyenv` and look for existing environments there.
If then user needs to restore default pyenv root they can just `unset PYENV_ROOT`.

Comment: perhaps worth adding that this is usually set in the users `.profile` or the like (or `.bashrc` if you want it to apply only to bash, etc).